# An application with .sdf database dont work on different computer

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I wrote an app with local database .sdf. I use ADO.NET Entity Data Model to connection purpouse.
My connection string seems like:

```
<add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

This app works fine on my developer environment: Win7 and SQL Server 2012. But crashes on different computers like WinXP with .NET Framework 4.0 and  SQL Server Compact 3.5.
Application turns on Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger with message:

> An unhandled win32 exception occured in App.exe [2512]

In Visual Studio returns:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7c812fd3 in App.exe: 0xE0434352: 0xe0434352

under address 7C812FD3 in dissasembly is only:

> pop    esi

Comment: What OS version and version of .NET is the app running on in your development environment?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional N 32bit and .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile